# Why do incoming transfers appear in my wallet later than in block explorer?

Tags: full-node, monero-wallet-cli, p2p

ok, so I'm running the standard monero client ( simplewallet ).

Twice now I have received incoming transfers from shapeshift.io.  The shapeshift interface notified me at the moment the xmr transfer was sent and provides a link to a block explorer to view the tx.  So clearly the tx has been broadcast to the network.

Yet nothing appears in my monero wallet for 1-2 minutes.

I tried the balance and the show_transfer commands.

I see that there is an incoming_transfers command, but I did not try it until after the tx already showed up.

I am used to bitcoin and other altcoins get getinfo, getbalance, list_transactions, etc all show incoming transfers as soon as they are broadcast/received.

It's kind of spooky not to see the coins immediately.  Also, I think it would be especially annoying during in-person exchanges.

"hey i sent you the coins".

"hmm, I don't see them."

"still don't see them".   ( 30 seconds later )

"are you sure you sent to the right address?!!".  ( 30 seconds later )

etc.

more than likely there is a way to see them immediately and this is me being a newb, but I wanted to raise the question because I think it is a rough-edge that newbs will bump into a lot, so maybe the devs can address it in the software somehow.

Comment: Do you have the auto_refresh option set? Most likely shapeshift and block explorer are just polling every second or something, and you are not checking quite as frequently.

Answer (score 6):

The explorer is likely listing the transasctions that are in the pool (ie, not yet mined). Recent simplewallet will show those with `show_tranfers`, as "pool".

Bear in mind that a transaction in the pool which hasn't been mined is not yours yet. If all goes well, it'll be yours soon, but you should not trust a pool transaction yet for large amounts if you think the other party might try to scam you.

Comment: *if you think the other party might try to scam you* -> what do you mean? Once the transaction is in the pool, it can't be cancelled, right?

Comment: Another might be mined which renders the first one invalid.